# $r$-regular graph, $r>2$ with a subgraph with specific property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, network

> Suppose, I have an $r$-regular graph with $r>2$. Does there exist a subgraph with $r$ nodes such that each node in the subgraph has at least $r-2$ connections with other nodes in the subgraph?

For some graphs, I have checked that this is true. For a $3$-regular graph a line with three nodes, for $4$-regular graph a cycle of $4$ nodes; for a $5$-regular graph and for $6$-regular graph this is true. Is this in general true? Or does it require more conditions to be true?

Comment: Just to check my understanding, you're asking for a subgraph with $r$ vertices, each of degree *at least* $r-2$, correct?

Comment: If $r$ is odd, then the subgraph would have an odd number of vertices of odd degree, in contradiction to the handshaking lemma.  In you example of "a line with three nodes", which I take to be a path of length $2$, one of the vertices has degree $2$.

Comment: What if you take $K_{r+1}$? Are you sure you mean *exactly* $r-2$ connections? It seems that someone other than the OP added the word "exactly".

Comment: @saulspatz Yes. I am asking for a subgraph with r vertices each of degree at least r-2. But these r-2 connections should be within the subgraph.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, my mistake. I am asking for at least r-2 degree. I will correct it.

Comment: What if you take $r=6$, $G=(V,E)$ with $V = \{1,2,\ldots,100\}$ and $xy$ as an edge if $|x-y| \equiv$ $1$, $2$ or $3$ $\pmod {100}$? It doesn't seem difficult to show that it does not have a subgraph with the required structure (the "extreme" vertices in the subgraph can have at most $3$ neighbours).